Attempt to read property "secret" on null
I'm trying to develop my first webapp with Laravel so I can practice a bit but I've hit a roadblock right at the beginning. I didn't find anything on google regarding this problem, and I already tried to test this in a fresh install. I'm using Laravel 11 and passport auth. The user "artist" is created but I always get this 500 internal server error for some reason with the message "Attempt to read property "secret" on null". I can't really figure this out so I'm trying my luck here hoping someone has solved this issue.
Whole trace is here
AuthenticationController.php
    public function register(Request $request)
{
    
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    // Hash the password before saving it to the database
    $validatedData['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);

    $artist = Artist::create($validatedData);        
    
    if (!$artist) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to create artist.'], 500);
    }

    $token = $artist->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;

    return response()->json(['token' => $token]);
}

api.php
Route::post('/register', [AuthenticationController::class, 'register'])->name('register');

ArtistController.php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:artists',
        'password' => 'required',
        'description' => 'nullable',
        'genre' => 'nullable',
        'url' => 'nullable',
        'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048', // Add this line for image validation
        'tags' => 'nullable',

    ]);

    $imagePath = null;

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');

        if ($image->isValid()) {
         
            $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->image->extension();
            $imagePath = $request->image->storeAs('public/images', $imageName);
            $imagePath = str_replace('public/', '', $imagePath);
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['image' => 'The uploaded image is not valid.']);
        }
    } 

    $artist = new Artist();
    $artist->name = $validatedData['name'];
    $artist->description = $validatedData['description'] ?? '';
    $artist->genre = $validatedData['genre'];
    $artist->url = $validatedData['url'];
    $artist->image = $imagePath;
    $artist->tags = $validatedData['tags'];
    $artist->save();

    return redirect()->route('artists.index')
        ->with('success', 'Artist created successfully.');
}

PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php
protected function createRequest($client, $userId, array $scopes)
{
    $secret = Passport::$hashesClientSecrets ? $this->clients->getPersonalAccessClientSecret() : $client->secret;

    return (new ServerRequest('POST', 'not-important'))->withParsedBody([
        'grant_type' => 'personal_access',
        'client_id' => $client->getKey(),
        'client_secret' => $secret,
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'scope' => implode(' ', $scopes),
    ]);
}

Response
"message": "Attempt to read property \"secret\" on null",
"exception": "ErrorException",
"file": "C:\\...\\PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php",
"line": 97,

Thanks in advance and please let me know if I can provide with some more code.

Did you follow these instructions? https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/passport#creating-a-personal-access-client

I did, still the same error. I tried again with those instructions from fresh but still nothing

Error Attempt to read property "secret" on null means that you are trying to get the value of key secret from a null variable. e.g. $somevariable->secret would be $somevariable is null. $somevariable should be an object. In your case, it would be $client in your createRequest method.

Had you run php artisan passport:install?
